# Trying to shutdown network computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, shutdown, remote-access

I currently have a Virtual Box VM with a bridged network.

For testing purposes I have a Win7 Host & Guest. The host can see the guest and ping to it etc. But when running the command:

```
shutdown /m \\Virtual-PC /s /t 0
```

Nothing happens, can anyone tell me what I need to do so that a network computer can be remotely shutdown.

Thanks

Comment: Have you the Admin privilege or not?

Answer (score 1):

The order of switches are strict. Try: `shutdown /s /m \\Virtual-PC /t: 0`

Comment: I will say, using my **Windows XP mode** VM as an example didn't work. The reason was because the computer name "is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer."

Comment: I found the problem, your order of switches are wrong btw, the network computer should always be defined before the shutdown switch. The problem was 1. The Firewall and 2. UAC Control blocking the actions. Changes to the security policies need to be made.

Comment: Okay... I always defined what is intended first, shutdown or reboot, before the computer name. Anyways, you should add your answer and select it as the correct answer.

Comment: From my experience, the order does not matter *at all* (except that `-i`, if given, must be the first).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `shutdown -m \\Virtual-PC -s -t:0` which we use on Windows.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, it would probably be worth disabling the firewalls of both machines temporarily and trying again.

Comment: This answer is basically the same answer I posted an hour before.